# Is there a way to find $n$ where $f(n) > g(n)$ given $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ without trial and error?

Tags: inequality

Given two functions $f(x):= 8n^2$ and $g(x):= 64n\log_2n$, how do I find the smallest value of $n$ in which $f(x)$ starts to surpass $g(x)$?

I've solved this problem with a program by simply going through all positive values of $n$ till $f(x)$ > $g(x)$. What I want to know is if there is an exact way to solve this?

I've tried all logarithm properties I could find over this inequality, but none yelds a direct answer.

Comment: Well, you are looking for the solutions of $f(n)-g(n)=0$, and usual numerical methods for finding roots will apply.

Comment: Remove the solution(s) to $f(x)=g(x)$ from the number line and you get a union of non-intersecting open intervals. In each of those intervals either f(n) < g(n) or f(n) > g(n).

Answer (score 0):

We assume that $n$ is a positive integer.
Simplifying, your inequality reads $n>8 \log_2(n)$ or $n>\log_2(n^8)$ or $2^n > n^8$.
Start with powers of two and find the smallest $k$ that gives the previous inequality with $n=2^k$. This gives $2^{2^k}>(2^k)^8$ or $2^k>8k$. This inequality is simple enough to find that $k=6$.

Now you know that $2^5 <n<2^6$ so you have to try all numbers between 32 and 64.

Comment: You don't have to try *all* of them. Repeated bisection would find it in 5 steps.